# Parsing XML in T-SQL - ABS data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm after some assistance parsing an xml file provided by the Australian Bureau of Statistics. I've read over everything I can find here and online, and am not having much luck reading this data.

This is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<message:MessageGroup xmlns:message="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXGenericData.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXMessage.xsd">
  <Header xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message">
    <ID>none</ID>
    <Test>false</Test>
    <Truncated>false</Truncated>
    <Prepared>2018-02-14T22:41:03</Prepared>
    <Sender id="ABS">
      <Name xml:lang="en">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
      <Name xml:lang="fr">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <DataSet keyFamilyURI="http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetKeyFamily/RES_PROP_INDEX">
    <KeyFamilyRef>RES_PROP_INDEX</KeyFamilyRef>
    <Series>
      <SeriesKey>
        <Value concept="MEASURE" value="1" />
        <Value concept="PROP_TYPE" value="3" />
        <Value concept="ASGS_2011" value="3GBRI" />
        <Value concept="FREQUENCY" value="Q" />
      </SeriesKey>
      <Attributes>
        <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P3M" />
      </Attributes>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q1</Time>
        <ObsValue value="112.7" />
      </Obs>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q2</Time>
        <ObsValue value="113.7" />
      </Obs>
    </Series>
    <Series>
      <SeriesKey>
        <Value concept="MEASURE" value="1" />
        <Value concept="PROP_TYPE" value="3" />
        <Value concept="ASGS_2011" value="5GPER" />
        <Value concept="FREQUENCY" value="Q" />
      </SeriesKey>
      <Attributes>
        <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P3M" />
      </Attributes>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q1</Time>
        <ObsValue value="114.4" />
      </Obs>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q2</Time>
        <ObsValue value="113.4" />
      </Obs>
    </Series>
    <Annotations>
      <common:Annotation>
        <common:AnnotationTitle>Statistical usage warning</common:AnnotationTitle>
        <common:AnnotationText>ABS.Stat beta is continuing to be developed.  Data will be updated as soon as possible following its 11:30 am release on the ABS website.</common:AnnotationText>
      </common:Annotation>
    </Annotations>
  </DataSet>
</message:MessageGroup>
```

The result set should return 3 values:

1. SeriesKey Value where Concept = 'ASGS_2011'
2. Obs "Time" Value
3. Obs "Obsvalue" Value

e.g  the first record would return a row like:

```
3GBRI | 2015-Q1 | 112.7
```

This sample would return 4 rows of data like this.

I've tried inserting the XML into an XML variable or a column in a DB with an XML datatype, and then using SQL's XML functionality, but I'm an absolute novice at this and am having trouble with the correct coding/approach.

Any advice or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest do get rid of the `<?xml blah ?>` declaration. This is only useful when you store an XML to a file. Within SQL-Server any XML's encoding is fixed to *unicode / UCS-2*. This can lead to encoding problems...

There are namespaces involved...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>
<message:MessageGroup xmlns:message="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXGenericData.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXMessage.xsd">
  <Header xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message">
    <ID>none</ID>
    <Test>false</Test>
    <Truncated>false</Truncated>
    <Prepared>2018-02-14T22:41:03</Prepared>
    <Sender id="ABS">
      <Name xml:lang="en">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
      <Name xml:lang="fr">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <DataSet keyFamilyURI="http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetKeyFamily/RES_PROP_INDEX">
    <KeyFamilyRef>RES_PROP_INDEX</KeyFamilyRef>
    <Series>
      <SeriesKey>
        <Value concept="MEASURE" value="1" />
        <Value concept="PROP_TYPE" value="3" />
        <Value concept="ASGS_2011" value="3GBRI" />
        <Value concept="FREQUENCY" value="Q" />
      </SeriesKey>
      <Attributes>
        <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P3M" />
      </Attributes>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q1</Time>
        <ObsValue value="112.7" />
      </Obs>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q2</Time>
        <ObsValue value="113.7" />
      </Obs>
    </Series>
    <Series>
      <SeriesKey>
        <Value concept="MEASURE" value="1" />
        <Value concept="PROP_TYPE" value="3" />
        <Value concept="ASGS_2011" value="5GPER" />
        <Value concept="FREQUENCY" value="Q" />
      </SeriesKey>
      <Attributes>
        <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P3M" />
      </Attributes>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q1</Time>
        <ObsValue value="114.4" />
      </Obs>
      <Obs>
        <Time>2015-Q2</Time>
        <ObsValue value="113.4" />
      </Obs>
    </Series>
    <Annotations>
      <common:Annotation>
        <common:AnnotationTitle>Statistical usage warning</common:AnnotationTitle>
        <common:AnnotationText>ABS.Stat beta is continuing to be developed.  Data will be updated as soon as possible following its 11:30 am release on the ABS website.</common:AnnotationText>
      </common:Annotation>
    </Annotations>
  </DataSet>
</message:MessageGroup>';
```

--The query will declare the needed namespaces and then use `.nodes()` to get the `<Series>` and a second call to `.nodes()` to get the nested `<Obs>`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic'
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS message)
SELECT ser.value(N'(SeriesKey/Value[@concept="ASGS_2011"]/@value)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Concept
      ,obs.value(N'(Time/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Time]
      ,obs.value(N'(ObsValue/@value)[1]',N'decimal(10,4)') AS ObsValue
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/message:MessageGroup/DataSet/Series') AS A(ser)
OUTER APPLY A.ser.nodes(N'Obs') AS B(obs);
```

The result

```
Concept Time    ObsValue
3GBRI   2015-Q1 112.7000
3GBRI   2015-Q2 113.7000
5GPER   2015-Q1 114.4000
5GPER   2015-Q2 113.4000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I'm after. What does the XMLNAMESPACES declaration actually do?